# Javascript Inserting an object "inside"(each index having object already) an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I hava a json response like `[{0},{1},{2}..]` and each index contains object data. I also have an object like `a{}` which also contains object data.What I want is to add the object a "inside"(at the end) the each index like `[{0..a},{1..a},{2a}]`.

Comment: can you sow expected output bcz, JSON object [{0..a},{1..a},{2a}] is not like this, It always contain key-value pair like [{0:"a'"}..]

Comment: do u want to add object to other object?

Answer (score 0):

So assuming your json response is in some variable (let's say its called jsonResponse) and a is an Object you can do:

```
jsonResponse.push(a)
```

Which will add the a object to the end of the jsonResponse array.

This assumes that jsonResponse is an array, if it is a string you may have to do something like:

```
let jsonResponse = JSON.parse(responsestring)
```

Comment: push will add the object at the end JsonResponse array but I want it to be inside each index of JsonResponse like JsonResponse [{0,a},{1,a}]. What you are saying will do this JsonResponse[{0},{1},{a}]

Comment: @Rizwan Ashraf see Syed Mehtab Hassan response which will meet your requirements.  Without understanding your use case: duplicating a like that seems like it may be bad practice.  Better to define it once and then have your code reference it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to add Object A to every Object in your JSON response?

If so try:

```
var jsonResponse = [{a: 1}, {a: 1}, {a: 1}]
var objToAppend = {b:2}

for(var objectInJsonResponse of jsonResponse){
    objectInJsonResponse.appendedObject = objToAppend;
}
```

This will result in:

```
console.log(jsonResponse)
[{a:1,appendedObject:{b:2}},{a:1,appendedObject:{b:2}},{a:1,appendedObject:{b:2}}]
```

Of course you can change the name of appendedObject to whatever you want the key to be.

Answer (score 0):

to combine two json objects:

```js
function combineObj(ob1, ob2) {
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(ob1).concat(Object.entries(ob2)));
}

var a = [{b:1},{q:3},{s:2}],
    b = {a:2};
var result = a.map(x=>combineObj(x,b));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the json response using **JSON.parse** then iterate over it and add the object inside each object

```js
var resp = '[{"data":"1"},{"data":"2"},{"data":"3"},{"data":"4"}]';
var arr = JSON.parse(resp);
console.log(arr);

var a = {
  data: 5
};

arr.forEach(function(element,i) {
    arr[i].a = a;
});
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not totally clear, but sounds like you want to look at array.map.

For example:

```
let arr = [{x:1,y:2},{x:3,y:4}];
const foo = arr.map(obj=>{obj.z=42; return obj})
console.log("GOT:", foo);
```